# Gitlab CI doesnt trigger pipelines on commit to the specified branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to trigger a pipeline on any type of change/commit (push/merge/webIDE etc) to a specific branch called test branch. Not sure why it doesn't trigger at all even after I make a change to a file in that specific branch.

```
    default:
      tags: 
        - specs

    stages:
      - validate

    Trigger job:
      stage: validate
      script:
        - curl -X POST -F token=$ENTDV_PL_TRIGGER_TOKEN -F "ref=master" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1252972/trigger/pipeline
      variables:
        CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
      rules:    
         - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "testbranch"'
```

Comment: Can you add the full `.gitlab-ci.yaml`?

Comment: added. there are other stages which are removed. I basically want to run the pipeline on any changes to branch *testbranch* ; except for its gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: There is the `only` definition to trigger jobs only for a specific case e.g. a single branch [ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)

Comment: I may havent mentioned that this bridge job YAML is present in Branch A and it is trying to detect changes to "testbranch". Would the below work?

`only:
   ref: testbranch`

Comment: Not sure if I understand the comment correctly. So if a change in branch `A` is pushed, the pipeline is meant to pull the latest version of `testbranch` and detect changes there? That seems confusing. Regarding the `only` statement: This means it runs the pipeline if changes are pushed to `testbranch`. The `ref` keyword is not necessary. An example for the `main` branch is provided in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Trigger job` to only be run when changes are made on testbranch, you can modify your `Trigger job` to the following:

```yaml
Trigger job:
  stage: validate
  script:
    -  curl -X POST -F token=$ENTDV_PL_TRIGGER_TOKEN -F "ref=master" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1252972/trigger/pipeline
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  only:
    - testbranch
```

The Gitlab CI documentation is actually quite good. Here is a link to how "only" works: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#only--except

From the docs: "Use the only:refs and except:refs keywords to control when to add jobs to a pipeline based on branch names or pipeline types."

You can do some other neat things like specifying only `merge_requests` or using regex for triggering jobs and what not.

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, I can add this bridge job in master branch and it will detect the changes in testbranch; will get triggered once changes are found?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "bridge job in master branch". You can add this job and push it up from master if you want and it will take effect immediately though. Any future changes to testbranch will trigger the job.